# If I have two consecutive Integers and I have the following formula $n(m+1)^2$ is it even of odd?

Tags: real-numbers

I am helping my sister study for the praxis exam of this study book, and I reviewed a question based on number theory. I see it involves constant integers my question is:

### If $m$ and $n$ are consecutive integers, which can never be even? Choose all that apply.

However, I am focusing on this particular one, \begin{equation}n(m+1)^2 \end{equation}
My question is based on these two substitutions which tell me that this equation is odd:
\begin{equation}1(2+1)^2 =9\end{equation}\begin{equation}3(2+1)^2=27 \end{equation}
These are odd. However, in the back of the book it says that this can be even are my substitutions wrong.

Comment: then it is even. cause its 8.

Comment: Since $m$ and $n$ disagree mod 2, we know that $n$ and $m+1$ agree mod 2. The outcome agrees with your $n$ as far as even/odd

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression $n(m+1)^2$ being even or odd depends on $n$:
$$n \text{ even}\Longrightarrow n(m+1)^2\text{ even}$$
$$n \text{ odd}\Longrightarrow n(m+1)^2\text{ odd}$$
That's because $n$ and $m$ are consecutive integers, so $n$ even implies $m+1$ even (analogous for odd). Seeing that

- The multiplication of two even integers is another even (same for two odds)
- The square of an even integer is another even (same for two odds) (This one's a corolary of the statement above).

(this statements have an easy proof using prime factors) you can conclude the implications a gave at first.